# ¿Como evitar el refresco de la pagina al enviar datos al local o sesion storage a traves de un formulario?

Tags: javascript

Estoy simulando un registro e inicio de sesion almacenando los datos en session storage pero al momento de enviar los datos, bien sea del registro o de inicio de sesion me toca llenar los datos 2 veces para que salgan las alertas del sweet alert. Es como si se refrescara la pagina o no se. agrego el e.preventDefault y deja de funcionar el simulador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para alcanzar la funcionalidad que esperas, tu EventListener debiera ser sobre el evento 'submit', incluido el `e.preventDefault()`. Este evento se dispara cada vez que envias un formulario. Actualmente estas escuchando el evento 'click' y es por eso que `preventDefault()` no tiene efecto.